# Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule, but no tax rules exist

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

After transferring over using `cart2cart`, a bunch of `duplicate tax rates/rules` were copied over to the magento site because of a `couple demo migrations before the real one.`

So ,i removed the rules that were `created, and now` there are none. But there are still a bunch of duplicate tax rate. I thought since I got rid of the tax rules I would be able to delete the tax rates.

However when I try to delete any of them I get the error message "Tax rate cannot be removed. It exists in tax rule"

But there are no tax rules..What am I missing?